# How to develop a shiny app that produces a scatterplot based on the 1st and 2nd column names of a specific dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to create a `shiny` app that takes a dataset name and produces a `scatterplot` where the `x` axis is the 1st column and `y` axis is the second column in the dataset.

So far I have tried this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
        textInput("dataset", "Please enter dataset name"),
        plotOutput("plot")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$plot = renderPlot({
                req(input$dataset)
                data = get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
                ggplot(data, aes(names(data)[1], names(data)[2])) + geom_point()
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, it does not do the job. For example, when I type the dataset name `iris`, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aes` part can be

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
        textInput("dataset", "Please enter dataset name"),
        plotOutput("plot")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$plot = renderPlot({
                req(input$dataset)
                data = get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
                ggplot(data, aes(.data[[names(data)[1]]], .data[[names(data)[2]]])) + geom_point()
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks :). Do you mind explaining what `.data[[names(data)[1]]]` does?

Comment: @bird you are passing string into `aes` which requires either symbol/unquoted column name.  Either `.data[[` subsetting or convert to `sym` and evaluate (`!!`) works.  Previously, there was `aes_string` which is kind of deprecated now

Comment: Actually `aes_string` also works and seems like a very good solution. I am not sure why it is soft-deprecated though.

Comment: @bird yes, it works, but I didn't use it because it may get removed in newer versions and then your code may fail